# I just want to rename a file in andorid app by using File.renameTo() funtion but it doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I just want to rename a file through android code my code is below. when I use fin.renameTo() function as in below code this rename function is completely ignored and it doesn't display any of message either true or false. my current API Level is 27

```
btnRenameFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    File fin = new File("/storage/sdcard1/VideoFiles/ADHM.mp4");
                    File fout = new File("/storage/sdcard1/VideoFiles/ADHM.mp4.xyz");
                    if(fin.exists()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (fin.renameTo(fout))
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Renamed Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Renamed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Does not Exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                   
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: We have not had read/write access to arbitrary filesystem locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) since Android 4.4. Renaming files counts as a write operation.

Comment: But in android 7.0 renaming of file is possible. We can successfully rename the files in sdcard by simple File.renameTo() function. Then how is it possible for 7.0

Comment: The rules around removable storage access can be modified by device manufacturers, as it is not rigorously enforced, particularly back at that version. So, perhaps the manufacturer of your Android 7.0 device did something that is allowing you to rename files at arbitrary removable storage paths. Do not assume that every Android 4.4+ device will allow you to do that, outside of the directories returned by methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()` on `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, kindly confirm whether renameTo() is successful with simple if statement.

```
if (fin.renameTo(fout))
    {
    System.out.println("File renamed successfully");;
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("File rename failed");;
    }
```

Since it is platform dependent and Exception is not thrown when rename failed.

Also, fout file format is changed to .xyz
Try ADHM_XYZ.mp4

```
File fin = new File("/storage/sdcard1/VideoFiles/ADHM.mp4");
File fout = new File("/storage/sdcard1/VideoFiles/ADHM.mp4.xyz");
```